# como hago para que me aparezcan todas las columnas del archivo excel, solo me muestra 10 datos de cada columna

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    require 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'; //Agregamos la librería
    require 'conexion.php'; //Agregamos la conexión
    $Archivo = 'C2JC65788.csv'; // Cargo la hoja de calculo
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($Archivo);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $numRows = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
    echo '<table> border=2><tr><td>PO1</td><td>PY1</td><td>RG1</td><td>RU1</td></tr>';
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $numRows; $i++) {
        $PO1 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('PO1'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
        $PY1 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('PY1'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
        $RG1 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('RG1'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
        $RU1 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('RU1'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $PO1.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $PY1.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $RG1.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $RU1.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $objConexion=Conectarse();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO archivo (PO1,PY1,RG1,RU1) VALUES('PO1, PY1, RG1, RU1')";
        $result =$objConexion->query($sql);
    }
    echo '<table>';
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stackoverflow, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes mostrar un ejemplo del resultado que tienes y el resultado que esperas tener, para que sea más facil ayudarte

Comment: ¿Y por qué debería mostrar más datos? ¿Cuántos debería mostrar? ¿Has verificado qué valor estás obteniendo en `$numRows`? Pulsa en [edit] completando la pregunta con lo que has depurado del código.